# java swing Failure authentification

Tags: java, sql, swing

hi everyone i'm developping a java Swing application on Netbeans 
in this block i have some issues when i try to authentify with login and password using an SQL request
the problem is that everytime i reveive the SQL exception message :"erreur gerant"

```
    if (user.getText().equals("root") & pwd.getText().equals("rootouss")) {

        admindao.sauthentifier(ad) ;
        EspaceGerant eg = new EspaceGerant();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenue Administrateur");
        eg.setVisible(true);
        dispose();


    } else if("root" != user.getText()  & "rootouss" != pwd.getText()){
            String sqlGerant ="Select * from gerant where login=?,password=?";
        try {

            PreparedStatement pst= conn.prepareStatement(sqlGerant);
            pst.setString(1, user.getText());
            pst.setString(2, pwd.getText());
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenue Gerant");
                 GerantBundle gerBun = new GerantBundle();
                 gerBun.setVisible(true);
                 dispose();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur Gerant ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace - for this you can add ```ex.printStackTrace()``` into your catch block.

Comment: sorry for the sql SELECT : i have to change it ( it's updated now)
yes when i put ex.printStackTrace(); :
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password='admin'' at line 1

Comment: ""root" != user.getText()" is not how Strings are compared in Java, you should be using ".equals"

Comment: oh yes there's some doubt about this but it works fine :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement syntax is incorrect:

```
Select * from gerant where login=?,password=?
```

should be:

```
Select * from gerant where login=? AND password=?
```